# I need advice on. Inventory theory, Decision making under uncertainty, Decision trees

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, model

I need advice on how to solve this problem. Topics I see in my school are Low Risk Decision Making, Decision Making, Decision Making Under Uncertainty, and Decision Trees The results must be shown with graphs, and explanation. The company bolitas is dedicated to the sale of balls, backpacks and caps. The company has 2 suppliers (x and y). The quality of their products is shown in the following table.

| Articles | Defective pieces | Probability for supplier x | Probability for supplier y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| balls | 2% | .80 | .40 |
| Backpacks | 3% | .0 | .30 |
| Caps | 6% | .20 | .30 |

The probability of receiving a batch of balls from supplier x is 70%. The orders made by the company are 2000 balloons per month. 1 defective ball can be repaired with 5 pesos. However, supplier y is willing to sell the 2000 pieces for 6 pesos less than supplier x.

Taking into account that the quality of the supplier is lower, which supplier should the pellet company choose in order to have higher profits?

Comment: Hi Miguel. What have you tried? Please see [tag:self-study] and check its scope and add the same to your post.